# Pass only existing parameters into method

Tags: python, properties

I have a code which pass variable into a method if this variable exists in property file.

```
if all(hasattr(globals().get('properties'), var) for var in ['NAME','VALUE']):
    return reader.get_smth(name=properties.NAME, value=properties.VALUE)
else:
    return reader.get_smth()
```

it's obvious that method `get_smth()` has default values for every passed parameter.

So how can i pass only existing parameters (`reader.get_smth(name=properties.NAME)` or `reader.get_smth(value=properties.VALUE)`) avoiding large number of `elif`'s

P.S. Parameters which have to be passed **more that 2**.

Comment: You probably need to clarify a little bit what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use named keywords `**kwargs` here. First we construct a dictionary that maps the names of the parameters of the `get_smth` function (e.g. `name`) to the names of the `properties` (e.g. `NAME`):

```
prop_dict = {'name': 'NAME', 'value': 'VALUE'}
```

next we can use the following approach:

```
reader.get_smth(**{k: getattr(properties, v)
                   for k,v in prop_dict.items()
                   if hasattr(properties, v)})
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into [star expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Try the following:

```
reader.get_smth(**properties)
```

This will unpack key-value pairs from a dictionary into arguments for the function.

The property names will have to be the same as the argument names though (it seems the properties are uppercase and args lowercase in your program).

Comment: Note that we do not per se want to pass *all* properties, nor that the names in the properties are the same as the function parameters (`NAME` vs `name`). +1 since the idea is correct :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah, yes. Good catch!